# Do I need an article here?

Tags: articles

Which of the phrases is correct and why? "This document assumes a general familiarity with ..." or "This document assumes general familiarity with ..." Google search gives me approximately equal distribution of occurrences, so I don't know which one is better. Would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OP's specific case, I think omitting the article is fine (as she says herself, both versions occur about equally).

But in related variants like *"I assume you have **a** firm grasp of English grammar"*, you actually *need* the article, to sound like a native. So if you're not sure in any given case, include **a/an**.

Answer (score 3):

David Crystal, probably Britain's most renowned linguist, has written a helpful article on this thorny issue.

Crystal refers to Quirk's (*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*) analysis of when the indefinite article can be used in front of a modified uncountable noun. Crystal cites Quirk as follows:

> The conditions under which a/an occurs in such cases are unclear.

However, there are two useful patterns that Quirk has identified. Firstly, it seems that the article is used if the noun "*refers to a quality or other abstraction which is attributed to a person.*" So,

> This document assumes a general familiarity with ...

is fine because *familiarity* is a quality attributed to a person. But the indefinite article is not correct in the following:

> *We made an important progress ...

since *progress* is not such a personal attribute.

Secondly, Crystal summarises Quirk as follows:

> ... the greater the amount of premodification or postmodification,
>   the more likely we will find the indefinite article.
>
> She played the oboe with sensitivity.
>
> ?She played the oboe with a sensitivity.
>
> She played the oboe with a great sensitivity.
>
> She played the oboe with a great and engaging sensitivity.
>
> She played the oboe with a sensitivity that delighted the critics.
>
> She played the oboe with a great and engaging sensitivity that
>   delighted the critics.

Crystal then goes on:

> Having said all that, I'm not entirely sure which uncountables follow
>   these trends. The semantic criterion (personal attribution) is
>   inevitably a bit fuzzy. Is *plagiarism* included, for example? Would you
>   accept *The teacher discovered a fresh plagiarism*? I think there might
>   be quite a lot of divided usage here.

The basic advice I get from this for English language learners is they should be aware of Quirk's two "rules". And in fuzzy cases such as *plagiarism* neither use nor non-use of the indefinite article is likely to have native speakers throwing up  their hand in horror at an egregious grammar mistake.

http://david-crystal.blogspot.de/2013/03/on-uncountability.html

Comment: Shoe, thank you for such a detailed answer! I'd love to give you a vote up, but I haven't yet earned enough reputation to do so. The answer to my question seems to boil down to "develop your gut feeling of the language and use it" :)